# error occuring while passing array

Tags: java

i am new in java coming from c++ and C. when i pass simply arr= 4  gives correct ouptput but when i pass arr[i]=4 it gives error. could someone tell me and correct me?

code :

package GA;

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class ReversedBinary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 0; 
        int i=1;
        int[]arr = new int[]{4};
       // arr[i]4;
    //    number=arr[i];

        if (number <0)
            System.out.println("Error: Not a positive integer");
        else { 

            System.out.print("Convert to binary is:");
            System.out.print(binaryform(arr[i])); // error occuring
        }
    }

    private static Object binaryform(int arr) {
        int remainder;
        if (arr <=1) {
            System.out.print(arr);
            return null;   // KICK OUT OF THE RECURSION
        }

        remainder= arr %2; 
        binaryform(arr >>1);
        System.out.print(remainder);
        return "";

    }
}
```

error:

```
Convert to binary is:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at GA.ReversedBinary.main(ReversedBinary.java:18)
```

Comment: Like in C, Java arrays are indexed from 0 => `int i = 0;`

Comment: Unrelated to your actual issue, but `binaryForm` has no reason to return `Object` so its return type should be `void`, or perhaps `String` (if you wanted the binary returned instead of printed).

Answer (score 2):

In Java, array indexes start at 0 :

```
int[] array = new int[]{4};
boolean valid = array[0] == 4; // Valid
boolean invalid = array[1] == 4; // Invalid
```

So what you need to do is initialize i with the value 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ReversedBinary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 0;
        int i=0;  // i is initialized to zero
        int[]arr = new int[]{4};

        if (number <0)
            System.out.println("Error: Not a positive integer");
        else {

            System.out.print("Convert to binary is:");
            System.out.print(binaryform(arr[i])); // error occuring
        }
    }

    private static Object binaryform(int arr) {
        int remainder;
        if (arr <=1) {
            System.out.print(arr);
            return null;   // KICK OUT OF THE RECURSION
        }

        remainder= arr %2;
        binaryform(arr >>1);
        System.out.print(remainder);
        return "";

    }
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

ur array arr[] has only 1 element in it

and ur `value of i is 1`

```
u are passing arr[1] to the method which doesn't exist for ur array arr.
```

When u are doing arr = 4 , it means u are assigning 4 to the arr[0].

When u had declared

> int[] arr = new int[]{4}, u have pushed and fixed only 1 element in
>   the array arr.

so,

> u cant push or assign any value to arr[1] , because it is not in array
>   / cant be pushed in array.

Try changing it as ,

```
int arraysize = //some integer value
int[] arr = new int[arraysize]
```

, note : arraysize is some int value which is the maximum element ur array can have.

or change the value of i ,

```
int i = 0;
```

Comment: i was about to edit my anwer for explain, but thanks to nielarshi, i hope reader could have understood

Comment: yea thnaks both of you and to all. these smaller mistakes for beginners takes time away. same happend with me.